# How to find average difference of cost of a customer's first order and subsequent order based on date field?

Tags: sql

The question is, "among the customer base who have placed more than one order, what is the average cost difference between their first order and their subsequent order?"

There is no specific RDBMS, this is a written homework question. Any would work.

I think I will need the following WHERE clause: `"WHERE COUNT(DISTINCT(O.order_id)) > 1"`

I am struggling with the last request to find the average cost difference between the first order and subsequent order. Will I need to sort by date, and then somehow reference the values of two orders and find the average of the difference of revenue between the orders? How could this be done?

The table is called ORDERS and below is a sample:

```
customer_id | order_id | variant_id | quantity | revenue | completed_at
1 | 123 | a1 | 2 | 30 | 2017-01-01
1 | 123 | d4 | 1 | 14 | 2017-01-01
1 | 234 | d4 | 2 | 28 | 2017-01-02
2 | 456 | d2 | 2 | 28 | 2017-02-02
```

Comment: please mention your RDBMS(like SQL-Server, Oracle)

Comment: I repeat, we need to know what DBMS this is. For customer 1 there are two rows with the same order_id, is that counting as one order then or is only the one with the highest variant_id relevant?

Comment: There is no specific RDBMS as this is a written homework question.

Comment: Variant_ID specifies which product was on the order.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know your whole table. just trying to assume your table. try to sort by date.
Im giving you an example-

Select Top 100 or.CustomerId, 
or.UnitPrice/(Select top 1 UnitPrice from ORDERS oders where orders.CustomerId=or.CustomerId  order by 1 asc)*100 as AvgValue
from ORDERS or group by or.CustomerId,or.UnitPrice 
having Count(or.order_id)>1 Order By 1 desc